# Returning an IEnumerable when querying a method using IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

If you have a method that returns an `IEnumerable` but inside returns an `IQueryable` will returning an `IEnumerable` force an execution even though `IQueryable` defers the execution?

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers()
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> customers = null;

try
{
    customers = from c in GetCustomers // IQueryable
            where c.Name=="JO"
            select c;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
    }
    return customers;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you return will be an enumerable and will defer execution until you start enumerating it. However, unlike an IQueryable, it won't be changed by any further operations on it.

For example, if you did something like `.Sum()` afterwards, it will be executed on the local machine, whereas an IQueryable may send the `Sum()` to a remote database or web service.

Answer (score 1):

Since `IQueryable` implements `IEnumerable`, when returning your object you won't be forcing anything.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx `public interface IQueryable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>, 
 IQueryable, IEnumerable`

Answer (score 1):

First, `IQueryable<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so you're not really "forcing" anything here, since the `IQueryable<T>` will just be returned, no evaluation necessary.

Second, `IEnumerable<T>` is usually evaluated lazily as well (via `.ToArray()`, `.ToList()`, `foreach()`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You will not force execution until you perform one of the following (but not limited to):

- `ToList()`
- `FirstOrDefault()`

The code is not executed until the collection is physically required; e.g. as a DataSource.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be forcing execution, since both `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` are lazily evaluated, and IQueryable implements IEnumerable so no conversion whatsovever is neccessary.

This actually poses a problem if your architecture is not adjusted well for this case - the returned `IQueryable` only executes the query once the results are evaluated (i.e. when you iterate the results). If the DB connection has been closed at that point you will get an exception.